# Pandas merge on Index but columns shifted by 1

Tags: python, pandas

My first dataframe looks like this, df:

```
lastUpdated          midprice   returns
2020-05-12 00:19:10   0.000200    NaN
2020-05-12 00:19:20   0.000200  0.000000
2020-05-12 00:19:30   0.000200  0.000025
...
2020-05-12 06:56:40   0.000206  -0.000049
2020-05-12 06:56:50   0.000206  0.000000
2020-05-12 06:57:00   0.000206  0.000000
```

My second dataframe looks like this, df2:

```
                              ts         1.38259                lastUpdated
    lastUpdated         
   2020-05-12 00:19:10  1.589244e+12    3.36436     2020-05-12 00:42:32.202
   2020-05-12 00:19:20  1.589244e+12    3.34661     2020-05-12 00:42:23.399
   2020-05-12 00:19:30  1.589244e+12    3.34661     2020-05-12 00:42:23.399
   2020-05-12 00:19:40  1.589244e+12    3.15296     2020-05-12 00:40:47.384
    ...

    2020-05-12 06:59:30 1.589267e+12    35.121100   2020-05-12 06:58:24.165
    2020-05-12 06:59:40 1.589267e+12    35.121100   2020-05-12 06:58:24.165
    2020-05-12 06:59:50 1.589267e+12    35.521100   2020-05-12 06:57:31.452
```

What I need to do is to merge the dataframe like the below:

```
lastUpdated          midprice   returns   1.38259

2020-05-12 00:19:10   0.000200    NaN     3.34661
2020-05-12 00:19:20   0.000200  0.000000  3.34661
2020-05-12 00:19:30   0.000200  0.000025  3.15296

....
```

So the column `1.38259` is shifted by `Index+1`, I tried to do with `merge` but I am unable to do `Index+1`, I do not know if you understand what I try to achieve... any help? thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

you can create a new df2 column with the shifted column and then merge it normally with df1:

```
df2["shifted_col"] = df2["1.38259"].shift(1)
new_df = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

before merging, shift the column '1.38259' **up**:
`df2['1.38259'] = df2['1.38259'].shift(-1)`